Finding Oyama OVOP community
I would like to visit Oyama villege in Oita. Because I would like to see the original of One Village One Product project there.
After I search the Internet and read some books. I don't found any Oyama villege. It might not be an attractive site. Also when I browse Oyama oita in Google map. I found an area, but it is farm zone. I expect to see shop or community building there.
Where can I find Oyama village, OVOP museum, or any thing related to the project?

I checked on Google maps, and Oyama has a couple of towns/villages.

The One Village One Product (一村一品) movement indeed originates from the town of Ōyama, but the town ceased to exist in 2005 (it's now merged into the city of Hita) and the Oita branch of the movement is in any case operated centrally by the Oita OVOP Corporation.
Your best bet for actually sampling Oyama's OVOP produce and meeting locals involved would likely be the Mizube no Sato OYAMA, a Michi-no-Eki "road station" designed for visitors driving by.  For the record, Oyama's official OVOP products are:

旧大山町：梅、李、きのこ、クレソン、ハーブ、梅干し

Ume (Japanese apricots), plums, mushrooms, watercress, herbs and pickled plums.
Then again, Ōyama is no longer "one" village, so it only seems appropriate for it to have much more than "one" product.
